# como puedo hacer para que me arroje el resultado de los divisiores, todos en la misma linea y separado por comas?

Tags: python

```
x=int(input())
i=1
for i in range(1,x):
  if (x%i==0):
    print(i, sep=",")
  i=i+1
```

como ejemplo si pongo el 48 me arroja los divisores de esta forma

```
1
2
3
4
6
8
12
16
24
```

a lo que yo espero como resultado:

```
1,2,3,4,6,8,12,16,24
```

Answer (score 0):

es facil
cambia sep=","

con end=","

codigo al final:

```
x = int(input())
i=1
for i in range(1,x):
  if (x%i==0):
    print(i, end=",")
  i=i+1
```

eso si al final aparece una coma y no se como arreglarlo :P soy un programador novato pero solucione tu problema

Comment: otra cosa en tu if x%i==0 no pongas parentesis porque es innecesario

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás imprimiendo en cada ciclo del bucle y por eso no te imprime la coma de separador. Para usar el parámetro sep="," debes imprimir un array y no un índice (i). Una forma para hacer esto es construir un array:

```
x = int(input("Introduce un número:")
A = []
for i in range(1,x):
    if (x%i==0):
       A.append(i)
print(A, sep=",")
```

Incluso no necesitas indicarle **sep** porque python añade la coma por defecto, para separar los elementos de un array.